# Does a simple query guarantee ordered documents by _id

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents, the _id is an Int64 based on the DotNet's DateTime.Now.Ticks  (with some additional logic to guarantee uniqueness).

Example document

```
{
"_id" : NumberLong(637680220534625572),
"variousProperties" : 123456,
}
```

If I do a simple query, such as querying all records between times:

```
collection.find({ "_id" : { "$lt" : NumberLong("637684488000000000"), "$gte" : NumberLong("637671528000000000") } )
```

Does the database guarantee that these documents will already be sorted by _id? Or do i have to also do `.sort({_id: 1 })` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default index are crated on _id [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-_id-index) if there are no other filter condition in the query it will always return sorted (ascending order)